# Can we eliminate or reduce the rate limit for comment votes when you have enough rep?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, comment-voting

I will often look over the body of comments to a question or answer and sometimes I'll find 2 or 3 that deserve to be highlighted. Invariably I'll try to click on the second one before 5 seconds are up. I understand that we want to discourage people from upvoting every single comment, but can we stop the hand-holding once you've proved you know how to use the site?

Comment: The other problem with giving unlimited votes is every time you click the "up arrow" it sends a request to the server. If everyone clicks 5 comments in less than 5 seconds.. That's a lot of requests. Just sayin.

Comment: I agree, but 5 seconds isn't _that_ bad... even with my habit of looking over most comments before thinking on voting on them.

Comment: @Seth Isn't the question just about the enforced time span between votes, and not the number of votes ("unlimited votes")?

Comment: @A.M. When it comes to comments that's pretty much the same thing. By "unlimited votes" I just meant no time limit.